# how to show the following problem on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

$Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_{n+1}$ be non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3\ldots,n\}$. Prove that there exists non-empty disjoint subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ of $\{1,2,3\ldots,n+1\}$ such that $$\bigcup\limits_{i\in A_1} Y_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{j\in A_2} Y_{j}.$$

Please give a hint for this problem. I am trying but could not proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Previously this was a hint. However, as @mindlack pointed out it does not seem to be straightforward to deduce from here there are two disjoint subsets.

**Attempt.** Define $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and let $\mathcal{P}([n])$ be the power set of $[n]$, i.e., the set of all subsets of $[n]$.

Consider the function $f: \mathcal{P}([n+1])\setminus\{\varnothing\} \to \mathcal{P}([n])$ such that $A\mapsto \cup_{i \in A} X_i$. The pidgeonhole principle implies that there must be $2$ different $A$s with the same image.

Comment: Sure, but afaik, you can’t simplify the equality, ie ensure that the subsets are disjoint.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Daniel, would you please explain more. What is $\mathcal{P}([n])$?

Comment: Sorry @kokuio98, I will give the definitions.

Comment: ok. got it. But I got stuck at the point where i Need to use the idea of pigeonhole principle.

Comment: The idea is simple, maybe the new notation makes it seem difficult... Notice that the domain of $f$ has $2^{n+1}-1$ elements and the codomain has $2^n$ elements. This means that the function cannot be injective, i.e., there are $2$ elements in the domain with the same image by $f$.

Comment: @Daniel, ok. Upto this fine. If the two sets in the domain are disjoint we are done. But it is not necessary that they MUST be disjoint. In this this case how we can approach?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$. That is, $e_i$ is the $n$-tuple where the $i$'th component is $1$ and all the other components are $0$. To each $j \in \{1, \ldots, n+1\}$ we define a non-zero vector $v_j \in \Bbb{R}^n$ by
$$v_j = \sum_{i \in X_j}e_i.$$
We then have $n+1$ non-zero vectors in the $n$-dimensional vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$. So there is a non-trivial linear relation among them. I.e there exists numbers $c_j \in \Bbb{R}$ with not all $c_j = 0$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}c_j v_j = 0.$$
Now define $A = \{j | c_j > 0\}$ and $B = \{j | c_j < 0\}$. And define two vectors $a,b \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ as $a = \sum_{j\in A}c_j v_j$ and $b = \sum_{j \in B}-c_j v_j$. Then we have
$$0 = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} c_j v_j = \sum_{c_j > 0}c_j v_j + \sum_{c_j <0} c_j v_j = a - b.$$
In other words
$$a = b.$$
This shows that both $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, since at least one of them is non-empty.

Let $a_i$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ be the coordinates of $a$ in the standard basis. That is,
$$a = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i e_i.$$
Since $a$ is the linear combination with positive coefficients of the $v_j$s for $j \in A$, which are themselves linear combination of basis vectors with positive coefficients, we have that $a_i>0$ if and only if there exists a $j \in A$ such that the coefficient of $e_i$ in the expression for $v_j$ is positive. And by the definition of $v_j$ this is the case if and only if $i \in X_j$.
In other words we have shown that $a_i > 0 \iff i \in \cup_{j\in A}X_j$.

Similarly we write
$$b = \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i e_i.$$
And similarly we have $b_i > 0 \iff i \in \cup_{j \in B}X_j$.
But since $a = b$ we have $a_i = b_i$ for all $i$. Hence $\cup_{j\in A}X_j = \cup_{j\in B}X_j$. And this is what we needed to show since $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and  disjoint by construction.